# Extract filename parts to solve file name conflict

Tags: c#, regex

In a c# program, I want to write file, in a folder where other file may exists. If so, a suffix may be added to the file `myfile.docx`, `myfile (1).docx`, `myfile (2).docx` and so on.

I'm struggling at analysing existing file name to extract existing files' name *parts*.

Especially, I use this regex: `(?<base>.+?)(\((?<idx>\d+)\)?)?(?<ext>(\.[\w\.]+))`.

This regex outputs:

```
╔═══════════════════════╦══════════════╦═════╦═══════════╦═══════════════════════════════════╗
║    Source Filename    ║     base     ║ idx ║ extension ║              Success              ║
╠═══════════════════════╬══════════════╬═════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╣
║ somefile.docx         ║ somefile     ║     ║ .docx     ║ Yes                               ║
║ somefile              ║              ║     ║           ║ No, base should be "somefile"     ║
║ somefile (6)          ║              ║     ║           ║ No, base should be "somefile (6)" ║
║ somefile (1).docx     ║ somefile     ║   1 ║ .docx     ║ Yes                               ║
║ somefile (2)(1).docx  ║ somefile (2) ║   1 ║ .docx     ║ Yes                               ║
║ somefile (4).htm.tmpl ║ somefile     ║   4 ║ .htm.tmpl ║ Yes                               ║
╚═══════════════════════╩══════════════╩═════╩═══════════╩═══════════════════════════════════╝
```

As you can see, all cases are working excepted when a file name has no extension.

How to fix my regex to solve the failling cases ?

Reproduction : https://regex101.com/r/q9uQii/1

If it matterns, here the relevant C# code :

```
private static readonly Regex g_fileNameAnalyser = new Regex(
    @"(?<base>.+?)(\((?<idx>\d+)\)?)?(?<ext>(\.[\w\.]+))", 
    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture
    );

...

var candidateMatch = g_fileNameAnalyser.Match(somefilename);
var candidateInfo = new
{
    baseName = candidateMatch.Groups["base"].Value.Trim(),
    idx = candidateMatch.Groups["idx"].Success ? int.Parse(candidateMatch.Groups["idx"].Value) : 0,
    ext = candidateMatch.Groups["ext"].Value
};
```

Comment: Why don't you just check for file existence in a loop incrementing index by one until you find available file name?

Comment: Use `^(?<base>.+?)(?:\((?<idx>\d+)\))?(?<ext>\.[\w.]+)?$` or `^(?<base>.+?)\s*(?:\((?<idx>\d+)\))?(?<ext>\.[\w.]+)?$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aeeXLj/1)

Comment: @PeterWolf: it may be a solution. I'll consider it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: your regex seems to work as expected. you should post an answer

Comment: for last example, note that the OS consider `.tmpl` as extension and `somefile (4).htm` as file name, see this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/34KGGv). If you can adjust your requirement, I would stay with the OS meaning of "extension", getting rid of extension with `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExension` and then parse somehow the resulting string looking for the (optional) index at the end

Comment: thx @GianPaolo for the warning. My business requirement is to consider each *dot something* to be part of the extension so I'll keep it as is. But you are probably right in a more general way. I must be vigilant with some edge cases like "some.files.with.dots (3).xml" and "some.files.with.dots.xml" that don't return the same basename

Comment: @SteveB, I'm surely biased since I quite hate RegExp [_Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions". Now they have two problems_](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/). It sounds to me that it should be easier to work it out without a regex, but as I said, I'm surely biased

Comment: @GianPaolo: the right tool for the right job. Not always easy to properly answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?<base>.+?)\s*(?:\((?<idx>\d+)\))?(?<ext>\.[\w.]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3Cbase%3E.%2B%3F%29%5Cs*%28%3F%3A%5C%28%28%3F%3Cidx%3E%5Cd%2B%29%5C%29%29%3F%28%3F%3Cext%3E%5C.%5B%5Cw.%5D%2B%29%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=somefile.docx%0D%0Asomefile%0D%0Asomefile%20%286%29%0D%0Asomefile%20%281%29.docx%0D%0Asomefile%20%282%29%281%29.docx%0D%0Asomefile%20%284%29.htm.tmpl&o=m), results:

[image]

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<base>.+?)` - Group "base": any 1 or more chars other than newline, as fewa s possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:\((?<idx>\d+)\))?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?<idx>\d+)` - Group "idx": 1+ digits
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `(?<ext>\.[\w.]+)?` -  - an optional Group "ext":

  - `\.` - a `.` char
  - `[\w.]+` - 1+ letters, digits, `_` or `.` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

What you might do is repeat the `()` part that contains digits asserting there is a next pair. Then capture that next part with the digits as the `idx` group.

Make the idx group and the ext group optional using a question mark.

```
^(?<base>[^\r\n.()]+(?:(?:\(\d+\))*(?=\(\d+\)))?)(?:\((?<idx>\d+)\))?(?<ext>(?:\.[\w\.]+))?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?<base>` Start `base` group

  - `[^\r\n.()]+` Match 1+ times any char except the listed
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?:\(\d+\))*(?=\(\d+\))` Repeat matching `(digits)` until there is 1 `(digits)` part left at the right
  - `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `)` End `base` group
- `(?:\((?<idx>\d+)\))?` Optional part to match `idx` group between `(` and `)`
- `(?<ext>(?:\.[\w\.]+))?` Optional `ext` group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3cbase%3e%5b%5e%5cr%5cn.%28%29%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5cd%2b%5c%29%29*%28%3f%3d%5c%28%5cd%2b%5c%29%29%29%3f%29%28%3f%3a%5c%28%28%3f%3cidx%3e%5cd%2b%29%5c%29%29%3f%28%3f%3cext%3e%28%3f%3a%5c.%5b%5cw%5c.%5d%2b%29%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=somefile.docx%0d%0asomefile%0d%0asomefile+%286%29%0d%0asomefile+%281%29.docx%0d%0asomefile+%282%29%281%29.docx%0d%0asomefile+%284%29.htm.tmpl&o=m)

Comment: thanks for the very detailled answer. I selected Wictor's answer thought, because it's a bit simpler

Comment: @SteveB That is perfectly ok!